# How to handle long running operation in Sitecore website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wordpress, sitecore

I've a Sitecore website, where I created a webform on the website root (`DataImport.aspx`), which imports data from ***Wordpress to Sitecore***. On this page I wrote the code to get blog posts from ***Wordpress***, then for each post create a Sitecore Item & download all media to the `/uploads` folder.

This task takes several minutes to complete (around 10-15 minutes) as we are downloading a large number of media files & I'm getting **"Request Timeout"** error on browser.

After doing research I found that if we update the `executionTimeout` setting in `web.config`
it will work fine, but even after updating this to 6000 seconds I'm still getting the same error.

Another thing I would like to ask is what is the best approach when we are doing such tasks?
Like, should I create a background process or create a web service?

Comment: The better is to make a background worker that take the commands from the sql server, and do the job.

Answer (score 6):

You should use a Sitecore Job to take care of your long running operations, which will run as a background task, be non-UI blocking and allow you to give feedback to the user. You can even run them as a scheduled task.

Some reference articles:

- [Using Sitecore Jobs](http://briancaos.wordpress.com/2012/02/06/using-sitecore-jobs/)
- [Long Running Process Options](http://adeneys.wordpress.com/2011/03/17/long-running-process-options/)
- [Use the Sitecore jobs](http://sitecoreblog.blogspot.co.uk/2011/01/use-sitecore-jobs.html)
- [Sitecore: Ideal way to execute long running job](http://www.nehemiahj.com/2013/10/sitecore-ideal-way-to-execute-long.html)

Comment: Thanks!
Sitecore Jobs looks suitable for such tasks!

Answer (score 1):

Setting executionTimeout is the correct approach. If you set this high enough, your process will continue running. What you are seeing might be your browser giving up - however your process will continue executing in the background until terminated. If you do any logging as part of your job, you will see the logfiles getting updated.

Comment: Yes you are right! 
Can we change the timeout on browser-level then(I'm using Firefox BTW)?

Comment: found it!!!
Oen FF & type about:config,then search for 'network.http.connection-timeout' setting & update the value to desired from default 90.

Comment: Yah, depends on the browser. I think IE gives up after about an hour. The important thing here is, that the job keeps going regardless.